# NoSQL Offline/Standalone - Query GraphDB File directly without exe application?

Tags: database, neo4j, nosql, graph-databases, rdbms

Every relationship database can be used without the need for installation of any software or tools, as most of the query read/write is all done to read a file that stores data in a specific format.

Can the same thing be done with a graph database (doesnt have to be neo4j, i wouldnt mind an alternative) without installing software, or having terminal endpoint running for access to database?

**Example:**

- MySql is a db file you can query
- MSSQL is a db file you can query
- SqlCE is a db file you can query
- Sqlite is a db file you can query

**Neo4j:** You need to download, install, have running and query through ip address?
OR... pay higher rates (2-5x cost?) for graph DB hosting in comparison to RDMS which is so inexpensive, it's practically given for free for most web hosting services.

---

**Purpose and Reasoning for Question**

> I'm looking for some cost efficient solutions to run a graph database
> with all the bells and whistles, that i can run from web host or
> application (that only handle IIS and hard-file transfer services --
> maybe it can do netcore, but dont know if you can run graphdb through
> netcore as a module service).
>
> Yeah, MSSQL is doing it now, but it's
> limited in what it can do and handle, as well as the tutorials are
> lacking in how to properly write NoSQL queries as fluent as the SQL
> stuff...

Comment: Hmm. I doubt that all (or any) relational DBs can be used without needing prior installation.

Comment: @cybersam the reason you can do so is because of the way the data is formatted in the file object. the tool that's used to read/write handles all of the query logic, and the data is just stored into and pulled from file. so, yes, you should be able to do without installing anything, as the install service only offers GUI and background service to do polling requests (which can be done from a code that can read/write to said file).

Answer (score 1):

Well, i found the answer to my question, and it's "yes, you can create a standalone **graph.db** to query from (in neo4j)." However it's only limited to Java and not supported by other languages or frameworks.

Neo4j calls it an "[embedded](https://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/java-embedded/)" database. Which is exactly what i was asking in my question, though i was hoping to be able to use the services in a .net application, which turns out to not be [compatible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30892776/how-to-create-an-embedded-neo4j-database-in-c-sharp).

If anyone has any alternate solutions that can work with netcore, i would love to see it posted here. I'm happy to know that i was right, and that it is possible to run queries on a hard file. Just disappointed that because neo4j is native to java, the technology is only available to java apps. Has no one written a c# port yet? (Not [in-memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27957730/fast-in-memory-graph-database), but to and from hard file.)

Anyways, i'll continue to research and look more into all of this. Thank you.

Edit-1: [Graph database for .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/816055/graph-database-for-net)